# Custom Rest Api Java Authentication using Firestore

Tags: java, firebase, api, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering how to create a java rest api where there is possibility to create something like a "signUp" and "signIn" user authentication to firestore (given it tokens). Supporting it with endpoints which can be accessed with for example postman or swift or android app when the api link is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you would like to build a REST API which internally authenticates against Firestore? This can definitely be done by exposing the [Firebase REST API for authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) with the [Java binding for admin accesses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin).